# Validation in Telerik Report parameter

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am creating an HTML5 Telerik Report. I have two parameters like Start Date and End date. I want to validate these parameters in such a way that the duration between start date and end date is not more than 6 month.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to subscribe to the start DatePicker's [Change](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/events/change) event after initialization. From there you can set the [Max](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/methods/max) value for the end DatePicker.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const startDate = $("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
        const endDate = $("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker");

        startDate.bind("change", function() {
            // Get the date 6 months after the selected startDate value.
            let maxDate = this.value();
            maxDate = maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + 6);

            // Set the Max date for the endDate DatePicker.
            endDate.max(new Date(maxDate));
        });
    });
</script>
```